# Different results with "in" operator, Python

Tags: python

The result of this block of code

```
items = ['j','ak',(4,5)]
tests = ['j','as',(4,5)]
for key in tests:
    for item in items:
        if item==key:
            print key,'was found'
            break
    else:
        print key,'not found'
```

is:
j was found
as not found
(4,5) was found
And the result of this block of code

```
items = ['j','ak',(4,5)]
tests = ['j','as',(4,5)]
for key in tests:
    if key in items:
        print key+' was found'
    else:
        print key+' not found'
```

is:
j was found
as not found

Now, QUESTION IS: Why (4,5) in the second block is not compared in "tests" and "items", while the result for either of the blocks should be the same? Is it something with the "in" operator?

Answer (score 6):

Your second code will raise a `TypeError` for the last item which is a tuple, because you are concatenating the key with a string :

```
>>> items = ['j','ak',(4,5)]
>>> tests = ['j','as',(4,5)]
>>> for key in tests:
...     if key in items:
...         print key+' was found'
...     else:
...         print key+' not found'
... 
j was found
as not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

But in first one since you are using comma to separate the `key` with the string it doesn't raise any error.

Answer (score 2):

I think is because the last have a bug in the print.

Try:

```
items = ['j','ak',(4,5)]
tests = ['j','as',(4,5)]
for key in tests:
    if key in items:
        print key, ' was found'
    else:
        print key, ' not found'
```